# Is there a better solution than virtualenv for server side python code?

Tags: python, linux, deployment, virtualenv, server

I have been using [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and [virtual envwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for years while doing development.  Until recently, I have been lucky and the systems / servers (*nix) I deployed too have had no other Python applications running so I have never had to worry about conflicting `site-packages`.

Google searching didn't turn anything up for me, so I was hoping the community could help guide me towards a common approach to managing python dependencies on a deployed system / server.

**Clarifications**

1. It's an important note that the systems I am deploying to are single board computers with limited resources.  This rules out implementations such as using a VM for each application.
2. At the time of asking, I cannot fault virtualenv on any fronts (possibly because I haven't tried it on the server yet)
3. The applications I am deploying are, for the most part, system processes (web servers, boot loaders, logging utils, etc...).  Because these are run as background services (normally with root access) I do not know how virtualenv will fair.
4. I was looking to see if there was a common way to manage python dependencies server side before I attempted to use something that, in my eyes, is geared towards the development side of things.

Comment: There are certainly _different_ solutions, from tools like zc.buildout to running each server as a separate VM in a container so they can have their own system site-packages, but if one were unambiguously "better" than the others, rather than each being good for different uses, we wouldn't have all this variety. So, what's wrong with `virtualenv` for your use case? What do you want to work differently?

Comment: @abarnert I should have stated this in the question, the systems I am deploying to are small single board computers.  So the notion of VM's just couldn't happen.  I'll have to re-evaluate zc.buildout, from what I recall it was geared towards packages within an app. Not about multiple apps on a given system.  Am I wrong?

Comment: You need to edit the question until it has enough information to answer it. Giving a vague half-answer in a comment isn't sufficient.

Comment: There are lightweight alternatives to VM e.g., [Docker](https://www.docker.com/whatisdocker/). You could use [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) to collect everything in a single directory.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what the problem is with virtualenv.  Can you give more information about why you don't want to use it?

Comment: @abarnert I hope I have added some clarity to the question (I was heading to a meeting when I wrote the last comment).

Comment: @DavidSanders There's no technical reason that I can see right now why it wouldn't work.  Check out my edit for more info.

Comment: OK, if you don't have any specific issues, and you're just looking for people to discuss the pros and cons of all the various possible options, that's a great question in general, but not a question for Stack Overflow. (The help explains in more detail why tool-shopping, subjective, opinion-based, etc. questions don't work here.) It's possible that [Software Recs](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) would be a better fit, but I really think you want a forum or mailing list, not a Q&A site at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have some other reason for not using virtualenv, it's production-ready and just as performant as your system python with system site packages.  Virtualenv is basically just a copy of your python executable in its own directory tree.  It works by invoking that separate executable instead of the system executable.  As long as your process manager/init scripts point to the executable in your virtualenv, it should work fine.